# Remoteclass class type missing

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex

Has anyone come in the scenario where some classes lose his class type on the client side?

Lets say i have this:

AS3

```
[Bindable][RemoteClass(alias="dto.someClass")]
public class someClass{
    //some public variables
}
```

java

```
package dto;
public class someClass{
    //some private variables

    //getters and setters
}
```

And i am getting a list from the server through a remote object.

Java

```
public List<someClass> someFunction(){
    //code creating a list
    return list;
}
```

AS3

```
private function remoteObject_resultHandler(e:ResultEvent):void{
    result=e.result as ArrayCollection;
}
```

But when u try `trace(""+(result.getItemAt(0) is someClass))`, some remote classes return true and some others false, and if i don't notice this, it gets worse when i send the array back to the server, because it ends up as a list of `flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject`, which i cant even cast to anything (I am getting a cast exception).

I am suffering of this with some RemoteClasses, and after checking the remote alias carefully, i couldn't fix it at all in some cases...

So, has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: I'm unclear if you're getting compiler errors or runtime errors.  If  your java service always returns an array; you may never create an instance of the underlying class object; which means it is never compiled into your final SWF which means it won't get automatically converted.  Although, I would think the trace which uses 'someClass' would force the class to be compiled; so there could be something else causing the issue.  For example all public getters/setters must be defined in both classes, and must have the same case sensitivity and be in the same order in the class.

Comment: no no no, you're absolutely right, i just noticed it got fixed with that line which left me speech less...

Comment: it appears that i have to do at least one reference to that object in my AS3 code or it wont be automatically converted...

Comment: Oh, and the trace result its false, but, the array now gets serialized fine after the trace.

Comment: nvm with the trace... show true too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, its working now, what flextras pointed out is true, i didn't have any reference in AS3 code for that class, i wonder why i saw a false trace too, but after fully recompiling, the server was getting the array just fine, and the trace showing true, so everything is goooooood =)
Now im wondering if this is a bug or something?
I am using flashbuilder 4.6 in eclipse btw.

Comment: This is not a bug.  This is expected behavior.  The Flex compiler optimizes out unused classes at compile time.  This keeps file size low and runtime code optimized.